# Center element inside display: -webkit-box

Tags: html, css

I have problems centering a span inside a div, which has `display: -webkit-box` and `line-clamp`. The text should **not** be aligned with `text-align: center`.

Current setup: https://jsfiddle.net/u2183bwm/2/

```
<div class="textContainer">
  <span class="fa-quote-left fa"></span>
  <div class="text">
    <span>
     Short text
    </span>
  </div>
  <span class="fa-quote-right fa"></span>
</div>


<div class="textContainer">
  <span class="fa-quote-left fa"></span>
  <div class="text">
    <span>
      text over 2 rowslongowrd but
    </span>
  </div>
  <span class="fa-quote-right fa"></span>
</div>

<div class="textContainer">
  <span class="fa-quote-left fa"></span>
  <div class="text">
    <span>
      Super long text which will be truncated after two rows through line-clamp
    </span>
  </div>
  <span class="fa-quote-right fa"></span>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
   .textContainer {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-style: dashed;
        border-color: #e0e0e0;
        border-width: 2px;
        height: 53px;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        
        .fa {
          flex-shrink: 0;
          
          &.fa-quote-right {
            margin-left: 5px;
          }
          
          &.fa-quote-left {
            margin-right: 5px;
          }
        }
        
        .text {
          background-color: lightgreen;
          display: -webkit-box;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          line-clamp: 2;
          -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
          -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
          align-self: center;
          flex-grow: 1;
          
          > span {
            background: lightblue;
          }
        }
    }
```

Which results in:

[image]

My goal is to have it look like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: So, you don't want to center them with text-align: center?

Comment: No, that would look different then my desired result.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).